# Can a TideSDK app be submitted to the Windows 8 App Store?

Tags: windows-8, tidesdk, windows-store

Has anyone successfully been able to submit an app created with TideSDK to the Windows 8 app store? Any helpful tutorials around?

Apologies if this question is repetitive - I've been looking around for resources without much avail.

Thanks.

Comment: I'd ask the TideSDK folks if Windows 8 Store apps is something they've tested with/support.  Theoretically it should work (it seems all HTML5/JavaScript/CSS), but there are some restrictions on what you can and can't do in JavaScript wrt to the sandbox model in Windows 8 Store apps. Take whatever 'kitchen sink' sample they have and give it a go in local VS and the WACK - will give you a point of reference at least.